# Python encode type error

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm using beautifulsoup and lxml to parse a html page. In the beginning I'm using the following code

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", { "class" : re.compile(r"^(s|sb)$") }):
    data_item = (''.join(str(item.find(text=True)))).strip().lower();
```

I got the following error

```
 data_item = (''.join(str(item.find(text=True)))).strip().lower();
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20), I changed my code to the following

```
for item in soup.find_all("td", { "class" : re.compile(r"^(s|sb)$") }):
      data_item = u' '.join(item.find(text=True)).encode('utf-8').strip().lower();
```

I got the following error

```
data_item = u' '.join(item.find(text=True)).encode('utf-8').strip();
TypeError
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the actual `TypeError` you get, including traceback?

Comment: It is the error I got. There is no other information.  File "get_financials.py", line 58, in get_single_page
    data_item = u' '.join(item.find(text=True)).encode('utf-8').strip().lower();
TypeError

Comment: Perhaps you should split up that line so you can find out what part of it is causing the exception. You could certainly do the encoding, stripping and lower casing in a separate step, at least, and probably other bits as well.